# How to use numpy-stl with file uploaded with Flask request

Tags: python, flask, numpy-stl

I am writing an app, which takes a STL file as input. I want to get volume of the stl object without saving the stl file and use the volume to calculate a quote and post it back to browser. Right now I am using `numpy-stl` package, but I am stuck on how to create a mesh object for numpy-stl from the file I get with `request.files['file'].read()`. Any help is appreciated.

[mycode:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVLOC.png)

[what I get for filedata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hggl8.png)

[what I get for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5BGF.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
import io

filedata = request.files['file'].read()
data = io.BytesIO(filedata)
tmp_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file("tmp.stl", fh=data)
```

You can use tmp_mesh object to do you interesting operation

suggestion to add error handle on something not expected

1. if request.files not contain 'file' keys